# Add <a> to images using javascript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a hyperlink to an image with the following format using Javascript (or JQuery, for that matter):

```
<a href="#linkgoeshere"><img src="#imggoeshere" /></a>
```

I already selected the div where the image goes in, I just need to surround my images that I found with a hyperlink.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to have your work done for you for free. Provide what you have tried and we can help fix anything that might not be working.

Comment: Well yes, it is possible. Add some JS code of what you have tried, or your question will vanish soon.

Comment: so there could be more than 1 img inside the div? are there any rules about which link URL should go with which img?

Comment: @giammin Not much, as I have no clue how to do it. I was trying to get it work with either .innerHTML and .outerHTML, but neither of them do what I want.

Comment: @giammin I see you editted your answer to something less polite: I don't see any reason to do so. As I explained 3 minutes before you editted your question, I have no experience with doing something like this, and using either .innerHTML and .outerHTML doesn't do what I want, hence I asked the question. It is clear to me stackoverflow is not the place to go if you have questions, since people like you make it very hard for others to be taken seriously. Remember, you don't have to respond to something you don't like. It seems .wrap() did the job, I don't consider that "doing my work for free"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this little thing will do the trick.

```
$( "img" ).wrap("<a href='#linkgoeshere'></a>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score -1):

```
var imageHTML = $('yourOuterDiv').innerHTML;
$('yourOuterDiv').innerHTML = '<a href="#linkgoeshere">' + imageHTML  +'</a>';
```